# oracle - no partition in window function but fill sequential numbers for acd properties

Tags: sql, oracle

I have acd properties table with 3 columns - id, acd and rpt. The rpt is set to 1 when it is first reported for the acd property, but if any consequent acd properties are repeating, it is set to 0. The id column is always incrementing (sort of pk). Now for the continous zeros, I need the sequential numbers starting from 2,3... as shown in the wanted column.

```
id  acd  rpt wanted
1   a    1    1
2   b    1    1
3   b    0    2
4   a    1    1
5   a    0    2
6   a    0    3
7   d    1    1
8   d    0    2
9   d    0    3
10  c    1    1
11  c    0    2
12  c    0    3
13  c    0    4
14  c    0    5
15  d    1    1
16  a    1    1
```

I tried the window function, but when I use "value" column in partition clause it is grouping all a's which is not desired. Is it possible to get the results as in "wanted" column given rpt and id incrementing.

Comment: is there a column to specify *ordering*?

Comment: updated with id column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need nested OLAP-funtions:

```
SELECT dt.*,
   Row_Number() Over (PARTITION BY grp ORDER BY id)
FROM
 ( -- calculate a group number using a Cumulative Sum over 0/1 (for partitioning in next step)
   SELECT prop.*, Sum(rpt) Over (ORDER BY id ROWS Unbounded Preceding) AS grp
   FROM prop
 ) dt
```

Answer (score 3):

When `rpt = 1`, then you want `1`.  Then you want the `0`s enumerated for each `acd`.  If this is correct, then the logic is:

```
select t.*,
       (case when rpt = 1 then 1
             else 1 + row_number() over (partition by acd, rpt order by id)
        end) as wanted
from t;
```

Comment: it should be (2) i.e row_number()+1 when id=5 and acd=a

Comment: @stack0114106 . . . Yes, I think the logic you want is 1 + row number.